# Process being stopped on a sequence of stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a stochastic process $J_t$ on a filtered probability space, $(\Omega,\{F_t\},P)$.

Suppose we are interested in a fixed time-interval $[H,K]$.

What does it mean for a stochastic process to be "stopped on a sequence of stopping times approaching time $K$?

How would one put this into a concise mathematical definition?

Comment: I will need more to answer this question : in particular, it'll be most helpful if you can give me the source of this particular phrase "stopped on ... $K$" : did you find it in a particular paper or book you  are reading? Perhaps more than one? If so then mentioning the source will be great. I know and can phrase , very roughly, what you are talking about, but knowing your source will make it applicable to you, although I'll also try to fill you in on a more general scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\tau_k$ be a sequence of stopping times (which are random variables such that the event $\{\tau_k = i \}$ is measurable in $F_i$); the sentence you are quoting seems to consider $J_{\tau_k \wedge n}$ (where $a \wedge b = \min(a,b))$, and $\tau_k \uparrow K$ a.s.

As an example, you can consider $J_k$ be i.i.d. coin tosses, and define $\tau_k = \min \{i \geq k: J_{i-k+1} = J_{i-k+2} = ... = J_{i}\} \wedge K $.